# How can I build a query that will return objects that hold more than one specific foreign key?

Tags: python, django

```
class People(models.Model);
    name = models.CharField()
    surname = models.CharField()

class Votes(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField()
    people = models.ForeignKey(People)
```

I would like to write a query that will return a queryset of people who have more than one vote(how many foreign keys of Votes has People) . how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

People.objects.annotate(votes_count=Count('votes')).filter(votes_count__gt=1)
```

`votes` is a related name here, you can add this in `people` foreign key in `Votes` model.

```
class Votes(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField()
    people = models.ForeignKey(People, related_name='votes')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that's what I wanted, I added a related name and now everything works :)